# Redirect action to controller in different namespace

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have middleware that uses a redirect to call a controller which then displays a view.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    redirect()->action('Full\Namespace\To\Controller\ErrorController@fourOhThree'); 
}
```

I also have this as a route. When I follow the route the view is displayed fine. When I try and redirect using `action` and pass the namespace of my controller, laravel tries to find the controller in the base app. I get error

```
Action App\Http\Controllers\Full\Namespace\To\Controller\ErrorController@fourOhThree not defined.
```

When the controller is located at

```
App\Vendor\Myname\Mypackagename\Controllers\ErrorController@fourOhThree
```

I have namespaced my controller correctly as far as I can tell as it matches the other namespaced controllers in this directory. This is the only controller I am trying to call from an action.

`ErrorController.php` within `App\Vendor\Myname\Mypackagename\Controllers`

```
namespace Full\Namespace\To\Controller;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class ErrorController extends Controller
{
    public function fourOhThree()
    {
        return view('...');
    }
}
```

I think I am doing something wrong in how I am passing the namespaced controller to the `action` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding a '\' in front of the qualified name.

```
action('\Full\Namespace\To\Controller\ErrorController@fourOhThree')
```

Comment: Tried this. The error goes away, but the controller doesn't fire.

Comment: i dont know what you mean by 'the controller doesnt fire'

Comment: As in the redirect doesn't seem to do anything. Any code within `ErrorController` doesn't fire. ...I guess its a different issue now?

Comment: As well as the backslash, I needed to return the redirect; not just fire it. Thank you.